# Convert rows to columns with some conditions in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is my example:

```
id  value  name 

0     2    michal 
1     2    george 
2     3    tamer
3     3    ali
4     3    sayed
```

and according to the value, i want the result to be like this  :

```
name 
michal george 
tamer ali sayed
```

It's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` and the `GROUP BY` clause to concatenate all values in the field `name` based on the same `value` in one string :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`name` SEPARATOR ' ') AS `name`
FROM tbl
GROUP BY `value`
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c54ae/1)

Comment: this query make every grouped 'value' as one string , but if want to make every name as element in row to show it in table , how can i do this? .

Comment: @Islam El-shazly : Well, in sql server there is a `pivot` feature, in mysql you can do it with case statements (it won't be so elegenant).There is only one problem : how to detect if it is a last,first or middle name.

Comment: ex id  value 
   1   islam
   1   notulysses 
   2   ahmed
   2   mark
and want it like 
     c1      c1 
R1   islam   notulysses

R2   ahmed   mark 

i think it's more easy to validate the problem , ur advice use Pivot

Comment: @Islam El-shazly: Please, ask a question and give me a link to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989881/convert-rows-to-columns-with-some-conditions-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ' ') AS name
FROM table_name GROUP BY value
```

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is connecting strings of multiple rows based on the `GROUP BY`.