# Convert rows to columns with some conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pivot

this is the table

id      value  name

```
1    2    first
2    2    manger 
3    2    islam
4    2    cairo
5    3    frist 
6    3    manger 
7    3    ahmed
8    3    alex
9    4    second 
10   4    manger 
11   4    mark
12   4    london
```

want to make this columns as row and select with some condtions that all 'first'

```
     c1       c2       c3      c4 
R1   first   manger    islam   cairo

R2   first   manger    ahmed   alex
```

It's possible ?

Comment: you will need unique identifiers for each column (first - 1,manger - 2, islam - 3 , cairo - 4)(first - 1, manager - 2, ahmed - 3, alex - 4) and so on.

Comment: okay check the Q again ,, u mean this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `CASE` :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN `id`%4 = 1 THEN `name` END)) AS `c1`
     , GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN `id`%4 = 2 THEN `name` END)) AS `c2`
     , GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN `id`%4 = 3 THEN `name` END)) AS `c3`
     , GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN `id`%4 = 0 THEN `name` END)) AS `c4`
FROM `tbl`
GROUP BY `value`
```

[**Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81dac/13)

or `IF`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`id`%4 = 1 ,`name`, null)) AS `c1`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`id`%4 = 2 ,`name`, null)) AS `c2`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`id`%4 = 3 ,`name`, null)) AS `c3`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`id`%4 = 0 ,`name`, null)) AS `c4`
FROM `tbl`
GROUP BY `value`
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81dac/14)

Comment: but i don't know the columns name , i just wrote as an example ,
because i will write this query in wordpress plugin to select what i want , so want it in different way

Comment: @user3698516 : in what way?

Comment: sorry for miss under standing , ur query is right but there is an problem ,,, 
the first column only is return right , but the other returning null

Comment: @user3698516: If you are using `wordpress`, why can't you post your data with `meta_key`, `meta_value` included and how you want the results with sample output?

Comment: this is my real table [link]http://s28.postimg.org/xvohe4bjh/table.png)
if i wrote 
SELECT CASE WHEN `id`%12 = 1 THEN `value` END AS `c1`
FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE 1
GROUP BY `lead_id` it return a value right ,, if write
SELECT CASE WHEN `id`%12 = 1 THEN `value` END AS `c1`
,CASE WHEN `id`%12 = 2 THEN `value` END AS `c2`
FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE 1
GROUP BY `lead_id` return first c right and the c2 id null.

Comment: what are the column names in the table shown in image?

Comment: @user3698516 : Updated with example

Comment: last edit runs successfully , can i select specific row with more conditions form that table ?

Comment: @user3698516 : yes, you can use it as a temporary table.

Comment: @Notulysses -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993205/select-a-select-within-query?noredirect=1#comment36974777_23993205